# How to read pot values to arduino serial monitor only when you move the pot?

Tags: arduino

This code is for reading potentiometer and print the value to arduino serial monitor
but you get values even if you dont move the pot.

What do I have to change in the code to get values only when you move the potentiometer?

```
 void setup() {
 // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
 Serial.begin(9600);
 }

 // the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
 void loop() {
 // read the input on analog pin 0:
 int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
 // print out the value you read:
 Serial.println(sensorValue);
 delay(1);        // delay in between reads for stability
 }
```

Comment: Do you only want to write to serrial when the pot is moved ?

Comment: yes , I just want the check the value in my monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int oldValue = 0; 
void setup() {
 // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
 Serial.begin(9600);
 }

 // the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
 void loop() {
 // read the input on analog pin 0:
 int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
 // print out the value you read:

if (sensorValue  != oldValue){
 Serial.println(sensorValue);
 oldValue = sensorValue;
}
 delay(1);        // delay in between reads for stability
 }
```

You need to use a variable to hold the old value and compare it to the new reading.
If they differ print the new value and update the old value